# Schema for Google Analytics Premium and Google Big Query integration

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a client that has invested in GA Premium - I can see that they'd get a lot out of Google Big Query particularly from the readily available access to raw data. I've been researching Google Big Query and from what I can see I would get along with it well since I have good SQL skills.

I've been experimenting with the [London Cycle Helmet sample data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091?hl=en) that shares the schema for Google Analytics data.

Where my thought process is becoming stuck is on the daily partitioning of data. I want to ensure I can run all necessary queries and have and idea of how to formulate the data before proposing GBQ and switching integration on.

Once GA BQ integration is turned one, what schema will the data arrive in? Will I have to partition the tables myself from the command line or will the partition be created automatically?

How will I query the date paritions? Would it be something like this:

```
SELECT
  field1
FROM
  table2
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01')
  AND TIMESTAMP('2016-01-21');
```

Are there any other landmines I might be about to tread on that I've not mentioned? Pricing certainly seems to be next to free, I'm really thinking of un-foreseen technical barriers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Analytics - BigQuery cookbook has a lot of examples that you may help in this situation

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en

Example query:

Last 6 Days plus Today’s data (intraday) using multiple `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`

```
SELECT
date,
SUM(totals.visits) visits,
SUM(totals.pageviews) pageviews,
SUM(totals.transactions) transactions,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 revenue
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([73156703.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -6, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))), (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([73156703.ga_sessions_intraday_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
GROUP BY
date
ORDER BY
date ASC
```

Comment: Thank you - odd that I didn't uncover this link in my research, it's great!

Comment: I can't see an equivalent of a SELECT INTO statement. Is this possible in GBQ?

Comment: Yes--using standard SQL with BigQuery. Please see https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=657.